# Polkadot-JS API not reflecting changes on explorer or chain in local development

Tags: polkadot-js

So i created a simple frame pallet with an extrinsic. I called this extrinsic from the local explorer at 127.0.0.1:9944 and everything worked and events were generated. But calling it from the Polkadot-JS API has not made any effect.

```js
// substrate client imports
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');
const { mnemonicGenerate } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { keyring } = require('@polkadot/ui-keyring');
// const { Keyring } = require('@polkadot/keyring');
const { cryptoWaitReady } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { u8aToHex } = require('@polkadot/util');


// global variables
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9944');
const port = 3002;

cryptoWaitReady().then(() => {
    // load all available addresses and accounts
    keyring.loadAll({ ss58Format: 42, type: 'sr25519' });
});

async function createAccount(req, res) {
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider }).then(() => {
        cryptoWaitReady().then(() => {
            const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();
            const { pair, json } = keyring.addUri(mnemonic, req.body.password, { name: req.body.name, created: Date.now() });

            (async function() {
                // get IP address
                let ip = "127.0.0.1";

                // record creation and sign-in onchain
                const txHash = await api.tx.robot
                    .signIn(ip)
                    .signAndSend(pair.address);

                console.log(txHash);
            }());
        });
    });
}


// request handles
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// add account
app.post('/create_account', function (req, res) {
    createAccount(req, res);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

I don't get a transaction hash return value, i don't see any changes on-chain, i don't see any events deposited. Its just silent. Worse, it throws no errors.

My chain function is correct, that is not the issue.

```rust
#[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(1000)]
        pub fn sign_in(origin: OriginFor<T>, ip_addr: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult
        {
            // first check for if account id is present
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let user_id = sender.clone();

            // check for overflow
            let ip_address: BoundedVec<_, T::MaxIPAddress> =
                ip_addr.clone().try_into().map_err(|()| Error::<T>::IPAddressOverflow)?;

            let now: u64 = T::TimeProvider::now().as_secs();

            let nsd: SignInDetail<T> = SignInDetail {
                ip: ip_address,
                time: now
            };

            // select user
            let detail = <SignIns<T>>::get(&user_id);

            if let Some(_sd) = detail {
                // update timestamp
                SignIns::<T>::mutate(&user_id, |det| {
                    *det = Some(nsd);
                });
            } else {
                // create new signin record and update timestamp 
                SignIns::<T>::insert(&user_id, nsd);

                // user was just created
                Self::deposit_event(Event::Created(sender, now, ip_addr.clone()));
            }

            Self::deposit_event(Event::SignIn(user_id, now, ip_addr.clone()));

            Ok(())
        }
    
    }
```

Same thing happens when i add an account to the keystore, with password and seed.

```
 const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();
            const { pair, json } = keyring.addUri(mnemonic, "dave", { name: "david", created: Date.now() });
```

It doesn't reflect on the local explorer at 127.0.0.1:9944 . Please what am i doing wrong? Thanks.

But when i use the example here (https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx), using the `balances` pallet, it emits events, makes changes onchain and the changes and events are reflected on the local explorer at 127.0.0.1:9944 .

or is it because of this:
[image: reason]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72756583/polkadot-js-api-not-reflecting-changes-on-explorer-or-chain-in-local-development as I asked here - provide more details, else this will be closed as too little info provided

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what's an example of a default function that you tried to call that's not from a default pallet? did you try refreshing your browser after restarting your node?

Comment: Please share the entire JS code you have - the problem may be how your app is subscribing to state (e.g ‘UseState’)